# how to execute es6 scripts from CLI

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, command-line-interface

I have the latest NodeJS installed and for any JavaScript files, I can execute it with `node myscript.js` but recently I'm learning es6 and for some of the latest syntax, it just pop out some errors/exceptions while executing. I tried babel-cli, but didn't seem to work as it is for compile es6 to 5 not for command line execute.

Comment: depends on which features your are using, latest node has a good but partial ES6 support (no modules for example). If you want use node, try babel-node https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/

Comment: a better place to play with es6: https://babeljs.io/repl/

Answer (score 56, accepted):

1) To enable the support of ES6, use the `--harmony` flag:

```
node --harmony myscript.js
```

This will enable the available ES6 syntax in node. But notice it's currently a limited subset of the ES6 standard (see the [compatibility table](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/)).

2) To have a complete compatibility, you have to use [babel node](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-node).
Install `@babel/node` to get a `babel-node` executable which works exactly the same as Node.js's CLI, only it will compile ES6 code before running it.

```
babel-node myscript.js
```

Comment: Here is a compatibility table that shows which es6 features are available in different versions of node: https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

Comment: I installed the babel-cli globally and try to run the file with the following content: var [a, b, c] = [1, 2, 3, 4]; console.log(a, b, c); it said syntax error, but shouldn't this be a simple destructuring of es6?

Comment: npx babel-node myscript

Comment: `babel-node` seems to not exist any more!?! I tried both installing the linked in "babel cli" globally by `npm install -g @babel/cli`, and by trying to run it using `npx babel-node`.

Comment: @FooF I edited the answer to account for the ever-breaking world of JS.

Comment: I needed to change the file extension to mjs for it to work

Answer (score 0):

For simple ES6 or even Typescript experimentation, maybe [Deno](https://deno.land) could be considered nowadays. It supports newest ES (and TS) out of the box without needing any additional tooling.

Answer (score 0):

```
#source1
https://dev.to/geekygeeky/get-started-with-es6-javascript-for-writing-nodejs-using-express-544h

#create  dir /project1
mkdir /project1
cd /project1



#install babel etc
npm i @babel/cli @babel/core @babel/node @babel/preset-env --save-dev
npm i @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties @babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread --save-dev
npm i rimraf nodemon --save-dev



#initialize project1
#https://philna.sh/blog/2019/01/10/how-to-start-a-node-js-project/
npm init


#edit /project1/package.json
nano /project1/package.json

 "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "rimraf dist && babel src --out-dir dist  --copy-files",
    "start": "node dist/app.js",
    "start:dev": "nodemon --exec babel-node src/app.js"
  },




#edit /project1/.babelrc
nano /project1/.babelrc

{  "presets": [
    ["@babel/env", {
      "targets": {
        "node": "current"
      }
    }]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread"
  ]
}



#install express
npm i express --save


#open a bash shell


#create /project1/src
mkdir src
cd src




#edit /project1/src/app.js
nano /project1/src/app.js


import express, { json } from 'express';
import items from './items';

const app = express();

app.use(json())

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    res.json({ status: true, message: "Our node.js app works" })
});

app.get('/items', (req, res) => {
    res.json({ status: true, message: "Fetched all items", data: items })
})

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`App listening at port ${PORT}`));








#edit /project1/src/items.js
nano items.js
const items = [
    {
        id: 1,
        username: "John doe",
        cartItems: ['football', 'ps5', 'cd-rom'],
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        username: "Jane doe",
        cartItems: ['mobile phone', 'game pad'],
    }
];

export default items;






#open another bash shell
#run server
cd /project1
npm run start:dev


#keep the server running


#check your app via browser
http://localhost:3000
http://localhost:3000/items
```